# Client-side, JavaScript-based Miller Columns

Tags: open-source, library, javascript, css, user-interface

## Background

[Miller Columns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller_columns) describe a [user interface design](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/17220/15694) for browsing and [editing hierarchical lists](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/19017/15694). Some notable implementations include:

- [Frédéric Hardy's](http://miller.mageekbox.net/)
- [Christian Yates'](https://www.christianyates.com/blog/jquery/finder-column-view-hierarchical-lists-jquery)
- [Jonathan Fine's](http://jfine.bitbucket.org/docs/js-mc/)

## Problem

There are a number of problems with these implementations.

### Frédéric Hardy

[Demo](http://miller.mageekbox.net/) and [code](https://github.com/mageekguy/jquery.miller.js). This is nearly perfect, the main issue is that the hierarchy cannot be set up in advance. Ideally, the JSON code would resemble:

```
{ 'id': 'ID1', 'name': 'Name2', 'parent': false },
{ 'id': 'ID2', 'name': 'Name2', 'parent': 'ID1' },
```

Where the second item ('ID2') refers to its parent ID ('ID1'). Unfortunately, the `'parent'` parameter takes a boolean to indicate whether or not a parent exists. This means that using the library requires registering events and implementing the hierarchy data as separate files (requests), as far as I can tell.

### Christian Yates

[Demo](https://www.christianyates.com/blog/jquery/finder-column-view-hierarchical-lists-jquery) and [code](https://github.com/christianyates/jQuery-ColumnView). Seems to have some severe bugs (e.g., clicking on a category without children causes a child element to appear in the next column). No hooks for create/update/delete operations.

### Jonathan Fine

[Demo](http://jfine.bitbucket.org/docs/js-mc/code/index.html) and [code](https://bitbucket.org/jfine/javascript-miller-columns). The issues abound: awkward user interface (keyboard navigation using input field focus), not structured in a multi-column layout, large number of JS library files to include, no hooks for create/update/delete operations.

### Additional Implementations

Other implementations that are encumbered with problems:

- [Christian Heilmann](http://www.icant.co.uk/) wrote about [complex dynamic lists](http://alistapart.com/article/complexdynamiclists), which uses HTML markup in its [demo](http://alistapart.com/d/complexdynamiclists/order.html).
- [Buwei Chiu](https://github.com/bu) has developed [hColumns](https://github.com/bu/hColumns), with a [demo](http://hax4.in/plugins/hColumns/) that looks like it meets nearly all the criteria.
- [Martin Wendt](https://github.com/mar10) has written a [fancy tree](https://github.com/mar10/fancytree) jQuery plug-in that has a skinnable [columnview](http://wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/demo/sample-ext-columnview.html) extension, which uses [nested data](http://wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/demo/ajax-tree-plain.json), but only supports three columns.
- [Carsten Griesheimer](https://github.com/Jupiterrr) has written a [column-view-component](https://github.com/Jupiterrr/column-view-component) for the Polymer Web framework; the [source code](http://codepen.io/jupiterrr/pen/jFxLH) for the [demo](http://raw.githack.com/Jupiterrr/column-view-component/master/demo/index.html) is reasonably close.
- The [SmartGWT](https://code.google.com/p/smartgwt/) framework has [Miller Columns](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#featured_miller_columns) that use in-memory tree structures.
- The [GWT](http://www.gwtproject.org/) framework has a [Cell Browser](http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellBrowser).
- The [Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/) framework (GWT-based?) has [Miller Columns](https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/millercolumns), but its [plug-in demo](http://hene.virtuallypreinstalled.com/MillerColumns) has issues.

## Question

What JavaScript library meets the following criteria:

- reads a complete JSON document in hierarchical form (XML or HTML are suitable, too);
- creates a user interface with dynamic columns;
- fully and accurately documented (in terms of API and CSS);
- has a "back" button or horizontal scrollbar to handle any number of columns;
- offers events for create/update/delete operations;
- can have its UI updated by changing a CSS template;
- works in all major browsers (IE10+),
- optionally, has a search feature (with or without regular expressions); and
- is free, open-source software?

Vanilla JS, jQuery, MooTools, or Closure are fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After an extensive search, no suitably simple Miller Columns software surfaced. Here's my software that has the specified functionality:

- [Source](https://bitbucket.org/djarvis/miller-columns/)

The editing operations are equally trivial:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $.getScript( "js/columns.js", function() {
    var $current;

    $("div.columns").millerColumns({
      current: function( $item ) {
        $current = $item;
      }
    });

    /** Called when an edit link is clicked. */
    update = function( link, def, undef ) {
      $(link).on( "click", function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();

        ($current === undefined) ?
          typeof undef === "function" && undef() :
          typeof def === "function" && def();

        return false;
      });
    }

    update( "#new",
      function() {
        console.log( "new child of: " + $current );
      },
      function() {
        console.log( "new root sibling" );
      }
    );

    update( "#edit",
      function() {
        console.log( "edit" );
      }
    );

    update( "#del",
      function() {
        console.log( "delete" );
      }
    );
  });
});
```